# I'm having a issue using fancybox on bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, fancybox

I got this code:

```
<section class="call-to-action text-white text-center" id="Productos">
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
<h2 class="mb-4">Productos</h2>
</div>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="img/ImagenShowcase.png"><img src="img/ImagenShowcase.png"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="img/ImagenShowcase.png"><img src="img/ImagenShowcase.png"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="img/ImagenShowcase.png"><img src="img/ImagenShowcase.png"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="img/ImagenShowcase.png"><img src="img/ImagenShowcase.png"></a>
</div>
</section>
```

and when I use it with bootstrap doesn't allow me to click on the images to pull the lightBox, idk what to do, I have spent like a month on this.

Comment: There are no issues using fancybox and bootstrap 4 - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdZeRm?editors=1000 Please, create a demo where your issue could be properly inspected.

Comment: i know it doesnt have the images but there it is the "thing" im talking about https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJrjyg?editors=1100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This element makes all the elements below it inaccessible, remove it and it should work fine -

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eLJKRm?editors=1100

Another solution would be to add `pointer-events: none;` to that element:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGedrM?editors=1100

btw, did you really spend a month on this? You simply had to use mouse right click and then choose "Inspect element".

Comment: yes, i spend a month on that basically because i'm starting to use bootstrap and im learning by myself, i just started studying engineering :D